# css doesn't work for html helper in mvc4

Tags: css

i am working on mvc4 application with visual studio 2010 and get css problems.
i have many htmlhelperfor and input of type submit in my html page.when i set css style to my submit button, some properties of the button work correctly and others not, but when i do the same thing for htmlhelperfor, any property doesn't work for these htmlhelperfor. Even the color for validation message is not red althought i have specifically imported the required jscript files.this is my html.

```
  @model myproject.ViewModels.AuthenAdViewModel
  <html >
   <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/Affichag.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js">    </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js">   </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body >
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {

<fieldset>
    <legend>Authentification de L'Administrateur</legend>
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.logicielchoisi)
       @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.logicielchoisi, new SelectList(Model.lelogiciel, "LogicielID", "Logiciel1"), "-Choisissez un logiciel-", new { @class = "dropdl" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.logicielchoisi)
    </p>
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.utilisateur)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.utilisateur, new { @class = "editeur" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.utilisateur)
    </p>
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Motdepasse)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Motdepasse, new { @class = "editeur" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Motdepasse)
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Valider" id="lebutton" />
    </p>
</fieldset>

  }
  </body>
  </html>
```

this is the code obtained from the viewsource of internet explorer:

```
     <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>



      <html >
        <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
     <title></title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
     <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <link href="/Content/Affichag.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

</head>
      <body >
       <form action="/Administrateur/Verification/Login?returnUrl=/Administrateur/Administration" method="post">    <fieldset>
       <legend>Authentification de L'Administrateur</legend>
       <p>
        <label for="logicielchoisi">Logiciel:</label>
       <select class="dropdl" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Logiciel: must be a number." data-val-required="Vous devez choisir un logiciel." id="logicielchoisi" name="logicielchoisi"><option value="">-Choisissez un logiciel-</option>
      <option value="1">Gereur</option>
      <option value="2">Bon plat</option>
      <option value="3">Aime village</option>
        </select>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="logicielchoisi" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="utilisateur">Utilisateur:</label>
        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Vous devez introduire le nom de l&#39;utilisateur." id="utilisateur" name="utilisateur" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="utilisateur" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="Motdepasse">Mot de passe:</label>
        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Vous devez introduire le mot de passe de l&#39;utilisateur." id="Motdepasse" name="Motdepasse" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Motdepasse" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Valider" id="lebutton" />
    </p>
      </fieldset>

   </form></body>
   </html>
```

site.css and Affichage.css are css files which contain the editeur and dropdl  class used for the html page which are follow:

```
  .autreelt { height:70px; margin:0 auto 20px;  background-color:Black; }
  .editeur { width :200px; font-family :Times New Roman ; font-size:18px; height :20px;}
  .dropdl { width :200px; font-family :Times New Roman ; font-size:18px; height :20px; }

     input#lebutton { width :100px; font-family:Times New Roman; cursor :pointer; padding :5px 25px; background-color: Blue ; border: 1px solid #33842a; -moz-border-radius:4px; -webkit-border-radius:4px; border-radius:4px;  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.75); -moz-box-shadow :0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); font-size :20px;}
     input#lebutton:hover, input#lebutton:focus{ background-color:#399630; -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.75); -moz-box-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); box-shadow :0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.75); }
```

i don't understand why not or how to do in order to carry out what i want.The border for button doesn't work for the button , i also don't know why.

Comment: This is not just [tag:css], kindly add the other relevant tags.

Comment: You can inspect with the F12 developer tools and see why it doesn't is applied.

Comment: I have just set css for errors and it is correct. added style are given below.                                                                                                                      .field-validation-error{ color : Red ;}
                .validationsummary-errors{ color :Red; font-weight :bold ;}
                 .input-validation-error{ border :2px solide #f00; background-color: #fee ;}